# Div moves down, while trying to keep it aligned with others

Tags: html, css

I have one parent div and multiple child divs placed in one row. These child divs are created dynamically, and I don't know how many of them will be created in the moment of rendering page. I want parent div to have fixed width, and to have horizontal scrollbar in case all child divs are not visible. This works fine.
But when I have content inside my child div, that div moves down, and it's not alligned with other divs. 
I'm not sure where is the problem?

Here's the jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LSZZx/29/).

I tried to put `position:absolute` to inner content of child div, but that didn't help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added:

```
div {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LSZZx/30/

Comment: That's it! Thanks for fast response, I'll accept it, as soon as SO allows me :)